# Date format issue with 'HH' when storing to SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, date, date-format

I'm having an issue when storing a date to my local SQLite database in my Android App.
I am using a global date format:

```
public static final String DATEFORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssz";
```

Once I have retrieved a date from my Azure database and I then format it to a string so it can be stored in a SQLite database.

```
row.put(Constants.COL_DATE_START, (String) DateFormat.format(DATEFORMAT, DateStart));
```

It all seems to work fine except for instead of 2013-09-18 13:00:00+0000 I am getting:

```
2013-09-18HH:00:00+0000
```

For some reason it won't pick up on the 'HH' being an hour number. If I change it to 'hh'
it gives me 2013-09-18 01:00:00+0000 - leaving me 12 hours off.

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Isn't this a UTC-local time issue? Aren't you in a +1200 zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateFormat = sdf.format(yourDate); //java.util.Date
row.put(Constants.COL_DATE_START, dateFormat);
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually store a timestamp and format the date when I'm showing it. I know it doesn't answer your question directly but AFAIK it is considered best practice.

Comment: -1 That is merely opinion based. And no, doesn't answer question.